# SSRS 2016 email subscription html render

Tags: html, reporting-services, subscription, ssrs-2016, mhtml

I need to create email subscription for SSRS 2016 report with part of the report in email body.

I tried to google it but most of guides are related to just creating subscription or setup whole SSRS web portal.

I have hint to partition report for rectangle and use "render" as "html code" in email body (Comment properties). Is this possible? And if so then how it should look?

Edit:
Also if this is possible I want to use it to another thing. To change scale of report in email, this will allow to have one report in SSRS to use in web portal and for subscription (in opposite to create 2 reports, one with scale for users 1920x1080 and second smaller for emails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendering a report in the body of the email isn't a native feature of SSRS subscriptions. You can work around this, but there are several issues to be aware of. You can use a data-driven subscription to generate HTML encoded results. You can then use these results in the Comment box like you mentioned. In other words, it's not using anything from the report itself, you can even use a blank report; all the data is coming from the query in the subscription.

One obvious limitation here is that you can't really make any visualizations, even making a formatted table takes some work. Also, this code is very difficult to maintain since you have to append bits of HTML all around your data.

Another issue with doing this is that each email provider renders HTML differently. Companies that send out formatted emails test them with different providers and modify the code accordingly to get it to look right. If you're only delivering these internally, it might not be a big deal.

One alternative to look at would be using SSRS Mobile Reports instead. Users can use the app to view these reports natively in full screen on mobile devices.

Comment: :( As the report is in SSRS email subscription is needed to provide report to other departments without access to our domain. Also that email will be for sure open in outlook. I was thinking that through html I receive additional option to modify report, but from what You are say it inst possible without huge workaround, and report itself can be modified in future so it will be not proper solution. It looks like that I am forced to create hidden copy of report and redesign it specially for email subscription.

Comment: Rendering the report in the body of an email is the most native feature of SSRS subscriptions I know of. Chose MHTML as rendering format.